# Recover Data from Firebase Database and set in Toolbar Title

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, toolbar

I want to display in title Toolbar a data retrieved from Firebase Database. But it's not working.

The structure of the bank is basically:

```
Firebase Database:
- Companies
--ID
---name_company
```

Code currently:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar = null;

    private String mId_company = null;
    private String mNameCompany;

    private DatabaseReference mCompanyDB;
    private StorageReference mStorage;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarPerfilEmpresa);
            mToolbar.setTitle(mNameCompany);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            mCompanyDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Companies");

            mCompanyDB.keepSynced(true);

            /*  ID Company*/
            mId_company = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_company");

           /* Title Activity */
           mCompanyDB.child(mId_company).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mNameCompany = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name_company").getValue();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        }
```

When opening the app does not appear the expected title, the name of the Activity is appearing.
What could be wrong?

Comment: itterate and show all values of dataSnapshot (key,value) and you will see what are you receiving.

Comment: It's best to post an snippet of the actual JSON (as text) instead of an estimate of what your database looks like. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the title of the toolbar in the snapshot again.

```
mCompanyDB.child(mId_company).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mNameCompany = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name_company").getValue();
        mToolbar.setTitle(mNameCompany);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It works.
But when the screen is opened the first time does not appear. Need to go back and go again.
What could it be?
Looks like he's not calling in time. @AjilO

Comment: `addValueListener` runs on a different thread and normally the response from Firebase server takes some time (this is dependent on your network speed, among other factors). I am not aware if this can be resolved. I would suggest you to add a `ProgressDialog` that is created and displayed in the `onCreate` method and gets dismissed in the `onDataChanged` method. Again I'd like to emphasize that this might not be the optimal solution; but certainly gets the job done.

Comment: I understand. It can temporarily resolve yes.
But I will adjust my project because this screen is mounted through the ID sent from the previous screen. As soon as I send ID I will send the company name as well, as I have access to this data previously. I believe it will work. Thank you. @AjilO